# Expand a JPanel as large as possible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a `JTabbedPane`, in which I insert an extension of `JPanel`, in which I insert a `JSplit`.

My problem is that the Panel auto-set to the smallest dimension possible, the one that is just enough to draw the inner components, as in the picture. [image: aaaa]

Instead, I would like to have it as large as possible.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Show some code. Hard to know what is the exact cause of your problem without seeing how you initialize and add the components. Are you using a layout, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the component that makes up the tab is using a `BorderLayout`, by default `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`

Answer (score -1):

set `JPanel` layout `null` and add other componenets with required size. Hope it will work!

Comment: A null layout is never appropriate.